# When I turn my phone sideways, the mobile version of my slider revolution slider reverts to the non-mobile version of the slider.

Tags: wordpress, mobile, web, responsive-design, revolution-slider

[The site in question.](http://linq.mit.edu/sandbox/)

I created a slider/header using [Slider Revolution](https://revolution.themepunch.com/). I want the slider to display differently on mobile devices than on non-mobile devices (a video on non-mobile and a picture on mobile). This works perfectly until the user turns their phone sideways. This causes the slider to revert to the non-mobile version.

The simplest solution I could come up with was to make the mobile version of the slider display on tablets as well. However, I imagine this would result in the same issue if the tablet was turned sideways. Also, the client wants the desktop version to be displayed on tablets.

Please let me know if you have any solutions. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the cutoff points for the responsive transition? It may be that your phone in landscape mode is wider than the cutoff for tablets.
I don't know if this will work or if when the phone is in landscape it sends new resolution data to the server, but it seems worth a try.